# How to implement ATDD and TDD at the same time

Tags: development-process, scrum, qa-process

I highly appreciate your effort to provide me with real implementation.

**As example:**

For `scrum` process from requirement to `user story` and `acceptance criteria` and when to start design `TDD` and `ATDD`
maybe `login form` as example or any simple example.

Comment: Hi Mjd, this is a pretty broad question - can you clarify what you're asking for exactly?

Comment: I am confused about the integration between developers team and testers team in sprint does the tester will feed developer with acceptance test to start coding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot under the surface of this question, but I'll first try to answer the question directly.

Let's say I have this user story:

> As a visitor, I want to a list of restaurants within walking distance
>   of my hotel so I can easily get food.

First, from an ATDD standpoint, I would want to work with my product owner, stakeholders, and potentially even users to create a list of expected results. For example:

```
| Hotel           | Restaurants                       |
| Hilton          | Applebees, Bob's Burger, Luigi's  |
| Homewood Suites | Olive Garden, Luigi's, Wendy's    |
```

For these test cases we are describing outward-facing application behavior. When we get into coding, I would use TDD to test under-the-hood behavior. Some examples of tests might be:

- Correct calculation of distance
- Calculate distance only crossing at crosswalks
- identify unwalkable routes (highways for example)
- identify cut-throughs like parks

Generally speaking you will have many more unit tests (TDD) than functional tests (ATDD). There are cases where the line between the two is blurry.  This happens in very simple behaviors. For example, showing an account as active or inactive.

Comment: Nice...if we are agile, so we should follow test-first approach?and if we use scrum can we share more than scrum team in the implementation of PBIs.i am new at Agile and we try to be agile so execuse me about my questions

Comment: Test-first development supports agile principles, but it is not strictly required.